# back propagate doesn't work in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, backpropagation

I am a freshman in Tensorflow. Recently i want to fit a non-liner function"y = 1 + sin(x * pi/4)" with a two-layer neural network model. The code of program is following:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def check_mode():
        x_data = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
        y_data = [1 + math.sin(x  * math.pi/4) for x in x_data]
        w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,2],0,0.5))
        b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,2],0,0.5))
        w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,1],0,0.5))
        b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,1],0,0.5))
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver.restore(sess,"mode.ckpt")
            print("lay1: ",sess.run(w_1),sess.run(b_1))
            print("lay2: ",sess.run(w_2),sess.run(b_2))
            a = []
            for x_i in x_data:
                w_plus_b = tf.matmul([[x_i]],w_1) + b_1
                a_1 = sigma(w_plus_b)
                a_2 = tf.matmul(a_1,w_2) + b_2
                a.append(sess.run(a_2[0][0]))
        print a
        draw_point(a,x_data,y_data)
        return
    def draw_point(a,x_data,y_data):
        fx,ax = plt.subplots()
        plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'o-')
        plt.plot(x_data,a,'k-')
        plt.show()  


    def sigma(x):
        return tf.div(tf.constant(1.0),tf.add(tf.constant(1.0),tf.exp(tf.negative(x))))

    def first_function():
        x_data = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
        y_data = [1 + math.sin(x  * math.pi/4) for x in x_data]

        x_i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,1])
        y_data_i = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,1])

        w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,2],0,0.5))
        b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,2],0,0.5))

        w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,1],0,0.5))
        b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1,1],0,0.5))

        z_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x_i,w_1), b_1)
        a_1 = sigma(z_1)
        a_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a_1,w_2),b_2)
        diff = tf.subtract(a_2,y_data_i)    

        loss = tf.multiply(diff,diff)

        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
        train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(init)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        for step in range(100):
            sess.run(train,feed_dict={x_i:[[x_data[step]]],y_data_i:[[y_data[step]]]})

        print("lay1: ",sess.run(w_1),sess.run(b_1))
        print("lay2: ",sess.run(w_2),sess.run(b_2))
        saver.save(sess,"mode.ckpt")
        return

    def main():
        #first_function()
        check_mode()
        return

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

I not sure that whether and how do the  tensorflow complete the back  propagate automatically? I really do not want to implement the back propagate by myself. Is there something wrong about my code? Thank you very very much for your help!!

Comment: It certainly looks like it completes the back prop, *but* it doesn't look like you are training it very much.  Specifically, your training loop only goes through each data point once.  It is common to see many iterations.  I'd be happy to run your code and attempt to fix it if you put it in a single and simplest possible working script.  For example, get rid of the save and other unnecessary code that isn't part of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code is in https://github.com/xiaoyangzai/test/blob/master/back_propagate.py    Thank you again!

Comment: Than you again! I have figure out by loop 1000 times!  Thank you very very very much!!!! Thank you !!

Comment: On Stackoverflow, it is encouraged that you upvote instead of saying *thank you*.  I'll post my comment as an answer so you can either accept it as the answer or upvote it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks like it completes the back prop, but it doesn't look like you are training it very much. Specifically, your training loop only goes through each data point once.  Try many many loops through the data.